# How to show gitlab or bitbucket repos in a web application?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab

I have been given a task to integrate bitbucket or gitlab repositories into a website. This is completely new thing for me and i dont know how to start.

Requirement is to filter gitlab or bitbucket repositories and display them into a page and user can access them from this page.

- Jenkins (Git plugin as default plugin)
- Gitlab plugin
- GitLab CE
- Git

With the help of google i found that above things can be used for integration purpose to merge and auto build process.
I am not sure if above tools can be used for my requirement. If not, what tool should be used.

I would be really grateful if you can tell me any hint about how to fulfill this requirement.

We are using Angular2 and nodejs for client side and server side technologies respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refer to those git service providers' API for reference. They have provide information about how to get repositories info 
like [Gitlab repositories API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html), [Github repositories API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/).

Comment: Thank you, these links helped me alot